# Develop gvfs adapter for a web-storage service?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, gnome, nautilus

Ubuntu has a useful feature where you can mount and view files on an external ssh account, bluetooth device, etc., called [gvfs](http://library.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/2.22/#sect%3agvfs-gio)/[GIO](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/unstable/). Is there a developer's guide/tutorial for making a custom adapter to 'mount' from an external storage or web service, preferably in Python?

Comment: Very good question. I suspect there isn't one, but if you manage to create an example, I might be interested in adapting it for my 'Advanced GTK Techniques' tutorial (http://ptomato.github.com/advanced-gtk-techniques/).

Comment: @ptomato where is that? Link is broken.

Comment: The URL didn't survive the migration of GitHub Pages from .com to .io. It's now at https://ptomato.name/advanced-gtk-techniques/, but I'm sure it's outdated by now.

Answer (score 0):

http://git.gnome.org/browse/gvfs/tree/ has a couple of backends (allthough all written in C). I don't know of examples in python.

Comment: That looks like the code for gvfs itself? What code would be best to interface with another programming language (if possible?)

Comment: Yes, thats the gvfs code, which also includes a few filesystems. Isn't the gvfs stuff wrapped by pygobject as well?